# What causes XP to lose the clipboard?

Tags: windows-xp, clipboard

A few times lately I've been getting the error "Cannot open clipboard" when trying to paste.

Can I get it back without re-booting?

I've been using Arsclip for years as a clipboard enhancement. I'm not convinced that causes the problem as it persists even when I close it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using the PC in question via Remote Desktop from my Kubuntu PC at home. I've had other clipboard issues where the XP box gets items from the Linux one. I need to monitor the situation and look for patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when an application locks the clipboard, and either crashes, or just refuses to unlock it again. Unfortunately, the only method I've come across to fix it is rebooting.

The problem WOULD persist when you closed Arsclip if it's the perpetrator - consider finding a replacement, just for a while, and seeing if that works better.

Comment: +1, Beat me, can't rule out Arsclip - any program that interferes/integrates with the clipboard is bound to make some sort of changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly - but trying to help you diagnose why the problem is occurring.

It would be worth running without any clipboard enhancement. This would tell you whether it was that that was causing the problem or another application.

Also try and keep a note of the applications that you are using that use the clipboard to see if it's a particular action that's causing the problem or combination of actions. It might be that the problem only occurs when trying to paste images or formatted text.